# Custom principle in SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, identity

I'm trying to use my custom principle in my SignalR Hub's OnConnected method. I tried the following:

- Context.Request.GetHttpContext().User
- HttpContext.Current.User
- Thread.CurrentPrincipal

but no luck..

It keeps throwing error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal' to type 'MVCSample.Biz.Profile.MyCustomPrincipal'.
```

Is there no access to custom principles in SignalR hubs?

Thank you!

This is my hub code:

```
[Authorize]
public class MBHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _hubLifetimeScope;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;        

    public MBHub(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _hubLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest");
        _userService = _hubLifetimeScope.Resolve<IUserService>();
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        //var idn = (MVCSample.Biz.Profile.MyCustomIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal; <--- THIS DID NOT WORK

        //var idn = (MVCSample.Biz.Profile.MyCustomIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User; <--- THIS DID NOT WORK

        System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext = Context.Request.GetHttpContext();

        var idn = (MVCSample.Biz.Profile.MyCustomIdentity)httpContext.User.Identity; // <--- THIS IS MY FINAL TRY, DID NOT WORK

        string userName = idn.Name;
        string city = idn.City;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        _userService.AddConnection(connectionId, userName, city, Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"]);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Dipose the hub lifetime scope when the hub is disposed.
        if (disposing && _hubLifetimeScope != null)
            _hubLifetimeScope.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

Comment: `var myCustomPrincipal = Context.User`?

Comment: Can you share the code you tried so far?

Comment: please share code for your custom identity i.e. `MVCSample.Biz.Profile.MyCustomIdentity`

Comment: @HCJ it is a simple custom identity class to store additional information for user. (i.e. firstname, lastname, city) I would add its code, but I do not want to make the question code-heavy. It's working properly on controllers and views, just failed in this hub.

Answer (score 0):

You should build your own Authorize attribute

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        //put our custom user-principal into a magic "server.User" Owin variable
        request.Environment["server.User"] = new MyCustomPrincipal(); //<!-THIS!

        return base.AuthorizeHubConnection(hubDescriptor, request);
    }
}
```

And then apply this attribute to your Hub.

If you want more info on this, I blogged about this [here](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/261-using-custom-principal-with-signalr/) with more code samples

Comment: `AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation()` never gets called for me and just setting a principal in `AuthorizeHubConnection()` seems to be not enough. Any ideas?